# What is the diffrence between these three commands?

Tags: syntax, letter-makes-difference

Consider

```
F=1/((x-a)(x-b)) ; 
G= 1/((x-α)*(x-β));  
H=1/((x-r[1])(x-r[2])) ;
```

Using `Apart[]`, the partial fraction decomposition is done only for $F$.

I am using version 13.1.0

What is the difference ?

Answer (score 9):

sometimes you need to help Mathematica and tell it which is the variable to apply Apart on

```
F = 1/((x - a) (x - b))
G = 1/((x - α)*(x - β))
H = 1/((x - r[1]) (x - r[2]))
```

Compare

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Basically, change `Apart[G]` to `Apart[G, x]` to make it work.

I am not sure if this is a feature or a bug but I've seen this before so may be it is a feature. If in doubt, *always use* the form `Apart[expr,var]`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! Being blind, there are many things that I miss

Comment: @Nasser With symbolic coefficients Mathematica has no way  to decide which symbols are variables and which should be understood as coefficients. Variables ordering is essential in Apart and  documentation mentions that (can' t find now).